# Are all commutative operations also distributive?

Tags: arithmetic

The textbook I'm reading through at the moment is describing the axioms of exponentiation. Quoting directly from the book:

---

By the definition of the *n*th power of a number and the use of the commutative axiom, we can prove that

(ab)<sup>n</sup> = a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>

Proof →

- (ab)<sup>n</sup> = ab ⋅ ab ⋅ ab ⋅ ⋅ ⋅ to *n* factors
- ____   = (a ⋅ a ⋅ a ⋅ ⋅ ⋅ to *n* factors) (b ⋅ b ⋅ b ⋅ ⋅ ⋅ to n factors)
- ____   = a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>

---

I'm a bit confused by how this is worded. Is exponentiation distributive because (like multiplication) it's an iteration of commutative operations?

The wiki page on this topic is absolutely horrendous. I've tried googling for the answer to this, but all websites discussing it seem to be written for the common idiot, and only talk about the distributive property of multiplication, not the distributive property in general.

Comment: I'm not understanding why people are down-voting this. The question is very clear and the context is well-defined. It's a non-duplicate question about something that is poorly explained by practically all commonly used reference material. Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean the question itself is bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t actually make sense to say that an operation is distributive: distributivity is a joint property of two operations. For example, in the ring of $n\times n$ real matrices matrix multiplication is *distributive over matrix addition*, because $A(B+C)=AB+AC$ and $(B+C)A=BA+CA$ for all $n\times n$ real matrices $A,B$, and $C$.

Exponentiation of real numbers is distributive over multiplication of real numbers whenever it makes sense: $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ whenever all of the exponentiations are defined. However, the argument quoted in your question proves this only for the special case in which $c$ is a positive integer. That special case is indeed a consequence of the commutativity of multiplication and the definition of $a^n$ for positive integers $n$ as repeated multiplication. We then go on to *define* $a^r$ for arbitrary rational numbers $r$ in such a way that all of the usual laws of exponents true for positive integer exponents remain true; in particular, this distributive law of exponentiation over multiplication remains true whenever the exponentiations involved are defined. This isn’t directly a consequence of the commutativity of multiplication: that’s true only for positive integer exponents. It’s true because we *define* exponentiation when the exponent is an arbitrary rational number in such a way as to make it true.

The last step is extending the definition to allow irrational exponents as well. We do this in such a way as to make the exponential function continuous, and then we prove that this preserves the usual laws of exponents, including the distributivity of exponentiation over multiplication.

Comment: Idk why Op is confusing like this

Comment: @SathasivamK I fail to see how I'm the confusing one here. All resources I can find on this topic just say _____ is distributive because <some example of distribution>. They don't explain the relationship between distribution and other properties, nor how to prove if an operation is distributive. To rephrase that, suppose I created a new mathematical operation. How could I prove that the applied distribution of my operation is possible for all inputs?

Comment: @DeftlyHacked: That’s because if $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ are two binary operations on the same set, distributivity of $\otimes$ over $\oplus$ cannot in general be deduced from general properties of $\otimes$ and $\oplus$; it has to be proved using specific facts about the specific operations involved. Set-theoretic union is distributive over set-theoretic intersection: $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$. However, this isn’t consequence of the commutativity and associativity of union and intersection: it’s a consequence of the specific definitions of these two operations.

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is that the only way to prove distributivity is by generalization and example? I guess that makes sense. Kind of disappointed there wasn't a bit more to it than that.

Comment: @DeftlyHacked: I would say rather that for any given pair of operations one needs to find a proof specific to that pair of operations. In the case of union and intersection, for instance, we just check that the sets on the two sides of the equals sign have the same elements. In the case of exponentiation and multiplication, the proof is completely different (and actually depends on how we define exponentiation in the first place: the approach that we’ve been talking about isn’t the only one).